# Why do groups appear in different orders on report?

Tags: jasper-reports, grouping

I am currently trying to group data together based on a field "type" using iReports 5.6.0. It seems to work but spreads the groups into different places see example below:

What happens

```
ID      Name    Location   Type  Cost
1       C1       FRA        Car    2k
2       C1       FRA        Car    2k
3       Transit  USA        Van    10K
4       Custom   USA        Van    20K
5       C2       FRA        Car    4K
```

Expected Result:

```
 Example Data
ID      Name    Location   Type  Cost
1       C1       FRA        Car    2k
2       C1       FRA        Car    2k
5       C2       FRA        Car    4K
3       Transit  USA        Van    10K
4       Custom   USA        Van    20K
```

I wish the data to come out as the expected result below instead of groups seem to be split up (which I think is it the order data is fed into the report from the application)

I have tried using the keep together option but it doesn't seem to work in this situation.

Comment: user "order by  name" while fetching the records

Comment: If I order by name I would surely see custom appear in-between cars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When using grouping in jasper report to get **correct output** the data
>   needs to **already be ordered** according to the group expressions used.

See: [Grouping Data in JasperReports](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jasper/)

You can achieve this by either:

order your datasource through query `ORDER BY` or if using custom datasource for example [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator))

or

use the `<sortField/>` element in the report for example `<sortField name="myField"/>`.

- In iReport IDE open the Report Query Dialog "edit query" and click the "Sort options..." button (bottom of interface)
- In JasperSoft Studio open the dataset and query dialog, find the tab "Order" at the bottom and add your field(s)

Comment: That did the job perfectly using the edit query > sort options

Thanks!